# Is Ulichaporas Pasha a new request or a continuation?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf

When we say Ulichaporas Pasha in musaf on a rosh chodesh that is a leap year, is that supposed to be read/understood as a continuation of the previous request or as a new request?

(Relevant to how to understand prayer and how to answer the amens in the repetition.)

Comment: The minhag by which we answer amen after the "groupings" in that blessing is bizarre altogether. Nevertheless, for those who follow that custom, it seems obvious that one answers amen after the three grouped together (since they go together in all other contexts).

Comment: How many chazanim try to do it that way, and how many congregations follow along? :)

Comment: https://tora-forum.co.il/viewtopic.php?style=9&f=9&t=9